# python "set" and "in"

Tags: python-3.x, set, in-operator

I've got a little problem with set and in operator in python.Why is the index "in" the set, but not the actual value?
The code is following:

```
sett = {}

sett[10]="a"
sett[12]="b"
sett[31]="c"

print('a' in sett)
print(31 in sett)
```

output:
False
True

Comment: There are no sets in your code. `{}` is a dictionary literal.

Comment: You can initialize the set using set()

Answer (score 1):

When using "in" for dictionaries, it is going to search through the keys, not the the values. The dictionary is a series of key:value sets. So the there is no "a" key, but there is a "31" key. If you try:

```py
print('a' in sett[10])
```

This will return True because now it is searching the value for a specific key.